# Reset domain user password remotely?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7

One of my clients has taken his computer away from the windows domain to another office. He has now forgotten the password to his account. I told him he needed to bring the computer back to the domain for me to reset, it but he didn't like that suggestion at all.

Is there any other way to reset his password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Free & Open Source tool, try [chntpw/ntpasswd](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) - bootable CD/USB/floppy images available. Be aware that most virus scanners will warn you about the included tools, though.

Comment: Thanks, I used this to activate the local admin account which he could then use to complete the task needed. Tool worked great!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can use dial-up networking from the windows login screen to connect to a VPN to do the authentication. Not sure if the VPN needs to have been already set up, but if you log in as local admin you should be able to set it up "for all users" and then connect to the remote network from the login screen. I've done it with a Windows 7 client.

Comment: Even if the VPN connection is not already configured, you can login with local admin to configure it. You might need to use something like NT Offline Password Editor (http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) to set the password/enable the local admin account though. You can not reset domain account passwords without access to the domain.